# Add quotes after comma in one cell excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task, this is my record in excel

[image]

I want to it change to this result after i pasted

[image]

Then i use `&` to connect every cell in to one cell, and this is my result that i want.

[image]

Hope i can show my idea, i want to create sql insert script by excel. But i see problem in VALUE, hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prefix with an additional `'` and replace the `,` with `','`

```
Cell Value = ''1','A'
Cell Value = ''2','B'
...
```

If you need to change your existing cells, add a column with this relative formula in each row (where the original text is in column A):

`=TEXT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","','"),"@")`

Then copy all those and paste special as values.

Comment: I mean it work auto, because if 1000 record, i must add `'` in 1000 record. :((

Comment: Yeah, but it show `'1,A`, when i use `=TEXT("'"&F1&"'";"@")` it show  `'1,A'` .

Comment: fixed with the required substitution

Comment: Yeah! It;s work for me, but i have to custom it, `=TEXT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"','");"@'")` Thank you so much !!!.